# Creating a data layer on CARTO from an ical feed?

Tags: carto, web-mapping, parse, calendar

Has anyone ever made a map on CARTO from an ical feed? Given that it uses a standard format which includes a location information, I envision that I can scrape the data into a CSV then geocode the location field. Looking for suggestions for how to attack it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to transform the ical feed into one of the formats [that CARTO supports](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/import-api/importing-geospatial-data/#supported-geospatial-data-formats) (CSV, xls, shapefile, KML, geojson, etc).

Then, once you have transformed the file into a supported format of CARTO, you can import the file to your CARTO account.

Then, once has been imported, you can use the [geocoding analysis](https://carto.com/learn/guides/analysis/georeference/) or [the geocoding functions](https://carto.com/developers/data-services-api/reference/#geocoding-functions) to geocode the location field.

Comment: That transform need is very usual, I wrote a blogpost on writing a middleware that does a transform for another format so it can be used as a sync table: https://geomaticblog.net/2016/12/26/creating-a-collaborative-photo-map-from-flickr-to-carto-with-amazon-lambda/

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. We decided to write a python script that reads the feed and parses into a CSV. The script runs daily to update the CSV, which is stored in a location that is updated to Carto by connecting it as an external service: https://carto.com/learn/guides/data-and-sql/sync-real-time-data/#syncing-to-a-public-url

Comment: you have also this post on the topic from one of our engineers in CARTO https://ivanmalagon.github.io/blog/adding-data-to-a-carto-dataset/ if the answer is correct please mark it or add your solutions as a full answer so we can close this question, thanks!